# Spring boot websocket with stomp connectivity using postman- How to consume springboot websocket stomp api endpoint in postman

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, stomp

I am using SpringBoot-websocket with stomp protocol. I am able to send and receive response through javascript where i establish stompclient connection and see the streaming in browser. could any body tell how the same i can do in postman. the websocket url is getting connected. but the stomp url (app/test) is not connecting in postman.

I tried added Sec-WebSocket-Protocol as v10.stomp in postman header. but still not working. I want to connect stomp endpoints via postman. if anybody know the steps please comment.

Answer (score 0):

try adding "/websocket" at the end of the url